# Heat calculation with non-constant specific heats

Tags: heat-transfer, heat

It is always seen that the total heat energy of a material under a change in temperature is given by:

$Q = mc_p\Delta T$

But what if $c_p$ changes with temperature? I am asking this because I am trying to model a strip of metal as a fuse. And because we are practically melting the metal, the final temperature would be very high compared to room temperature. And from what I have read, the specific heat changes with temperature.

Comment: What about atmospheric effects as the metal starts to vaporise?

Comment: Do I have to consider it that far? As the metal liquefies the connection would have broken already and the fuse would have served its purpose @SolarMike

Comment: Liquid metal conducts electricity...

Comment: But if the fuse is suspended in air, when the fuse blows, the liquefied metal will explode away/ fall to the ground and break the connection, right? @SolarMike

Comment: if $c_p$ is a function of temperature, then you integrate